# How do I differentiate between request and response in an HTTPURLConnection?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, content-encoding

Hi I need to evaluate if a server supports gzip compression.

Therefore I want to set gzip as Accept-Encoding in my request and evaluate if the response of the server containts "Content-Encoding: gzip".

However I am not quite clear on how to do this with HTTPURLConnection. Especially when to query my Connection object about the response. I currently do:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) feedurl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    System.out.println("Current Accept-Encoding: "+con.getRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding"));
    //check the response for the content-size
    float feedsize = con.getContentLength()/1024f;
    //the server uses transfer-encoding=chunked and does not specify
    //a content length
    if(con.getContentLength()==-1)
    {
        //count the content size manually
                    CountingInputStream counter = new CountingInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        while(counter.read()!=-1)
        {}
        feedsize=counter.getCount()/1024f;
    }
    con.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this OReilly article](http://www.oreillynet.com/onjava/blog/2004/07/optimizing_http_downloads_in_j.html). It illustrates how to generate the request, and how to interrogate the response and then create the appropriate stream (normal or gzipped) dependent on what's being returned.